# How to manage docker backups

Tags: linux, docker

I have some questions about managing docker backups.
For backing up and restoring docker data volume, using another container is suggested in an official site as command below.
official site
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

backup command :

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

restore command :

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

But when the container has multiple volumes such as sonarqube official image, it cannot restore all the volumes, because only single directly is indicated at the end of backing up command.
Are there any better ways to backup and restore multiple volumes?

And what is the reason why backing up ‘/var/lib/docker/volumes/{container}/_data’ directly is not recommended

Comment: @teachi15: Since Docker is a "software tools commonly used by programmers", this is on-topic.

Comment: @VonC - You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the usage of the site. I should have posted a question at the end on Docker community.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any good ways to back up and restore multiple volumes?

You need to script such a backup: see for instance [**futurice/docker-volume-backup**](https://github.com/futurice/docker-volume-backup)

Its `BACKUP_SOURCES` has a a space-separated list if you need to back up multiple paths, when mounting multiple volumes

Comment: Thank you VonC. 
It worked. But how can I restore back up? 
Do I have to replace files `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` directly?